# IAP on LPC microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, lpc

This code is part of IAP on an LPC:

```
#define IAP_LOCATION 0x7ffffff1
...
unsigned long command[5];
unsigned long result[3];
...
typedef void (*IAP)(unsigned int [],unsigned int[]);
IAP iap_entry;

iap_entry = (IAP) IAP_LOCATION;

iap_entry(command, result);
```

Can someone explain how it works, especially:

```
iap_entry = (IAP) IAP_LOCATION;
```

```
iap_entry(command, result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef void (*IAP)(unsigned int [],unsigned int[]);
```

`IAP` is the type *pointer to function(`unsigned int[]`, `unsigned int[]`) returning `void`*

```
iap_entry = (IAP) IAP_LOCATION;
```

There is some code at address `IAP_LOCATION`. Treat it as a C function.

```
iap_entry(command, result);
```

Call the function

---

Typically, this happens when a piece of hardware contains a ROM with precompiled code. You have to tell the C compiler where this code is in memory, and what argument types it expects.

Comment: +1 yes - it's IAP entry point, (In Application Programming - blows flash).  There is some magic to do with that unaligned address- forget what.

Comment: The thumb bit must be set for a Cortex M.

Comment: do not forget to disable interrupts!! it might work, but it stalls when an interrupt occurs during IAP call.